# Campaigns tab not visible to admin, yet visible to other users

Tags: campaign

As an admin, I cannot make the Campaigns tab visible to myself. I have checked everything that I can think of, but no success:

- OWD
- Checkbox 'Marketing User' for my user account
- Access to Campaigns via sysadmin profile
- Campaigns is a tab of the standard Marketing app

Using the Workbench, I was able to query for Campaign objects. And I found some! Following the 'View in Salesforce' link, I was able to view the details of a Campaign. So I have access to the object and its instantiations, it's just that for some reason the tab is not visible to me.

A user who can see the Campaigns tab has a custom profile that was derived from the standard Marketing User profile.

What is special about that profile? How can I give myself access to the Campaigns tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the solution turned out to be easy: the Campaigns tab had been set to 'Tab hidden' for the admin profile. Who/why/when: no idea. But now I can see the tab.